# How to use the orientation with out using auto layout in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am just start to learning about Xcode. i need to create an app in which it should be able to view correct manner in all the view (Landscape, Portrait). Condition here is should not using the auto layout.
Is any other way to use the story board for the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Other way is you have to programmatically handle the frame and other things in the following delegate functions. I have shown code for landscape mode only

```
//THis only work for ios<6.0
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    if(interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {
            return NO;
    }
    else
    {
           return YES;
    }
}

//THis work for ios >=6.0
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if(interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {

        return NO;
    }
    else
    {     
        //landscape mode code     
        return ( UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight);

}



- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation=self.interfaceOrientation;

    if(orientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {
        //portrait mode code
    }
    else
    {
        //landscape mode code
    }
}
```